In which US state are you the longest from another state in the contiguous US?
In which state in the contiguous US (so not Alaska, Hawaii, Puerto Rico etc) are you the farthest from another state?

Is there a point to these trivia questions? And is Puerto Rico excepted from the distance from Key West, Florida?

I would say the furthest distance from California to Maine is further than Florida to Washington.

@WeatherVane Yes, I wonder how difficult (long) it is to cross a border to a state/country where something that might be illegal where you live is legal, e.g., abortion. There are a lot fo trivia questions on Travel.

@d-b the problem is that sometimes it means crossing to the next state over, sometimes it means crossing multiple state lines until you finally reach a “safe” state. Can you clarify if you mean “a state where there is a point furthest from any other state” (as in Tor-Einar Jarnbjo’s answer), “a state pair with the longest distance separating them”, “a state where the average distance to any other state is the largest”, or something else?

Can you please engage with the comments to your previous question before dropping another ill-defined trivia question?

@jcaron I mean what I asked.

@d-b, it may be clear to you, but I do not understand what you mean by longest away from, in your Europe question even more than in this one, but is it travel time and if so by which means. Is it from the center most point in each State to any point in a near state, is it also including islands belonging to that state and/or any other?

@Willeke Longest is distance. Duh! Why would it need to be centre point when I didn't mention that? Islands are a gray zone, because I don't know that much about the island situation around USA.

As I said, clear for you, not for others. Please edit both questions to get it clear for all.

Voted to reopen, 100% clear to me, and trivia questions are on topic.

This question is entirely unclear. As it currently stands I could interpret it many ways (as others already have) so many answers are possible. You need o edit your post to include all the assumptions you have decided to make.

d-b - be aware that a) your comment does not meet our "be nice" guidance - be aware using this site is reliant on your good behaviour, and b) if your question can generate multiple relevant answers it is unlikely to be a good fit on Stack Exchange, where we ideally want one correct and complete answer to a question.

@d-b, the now deleted comments were also against the 'be nice' rules.

Just by looking at the map, I am pretty sure that the answer is Key West in Florida. From there, the closest other state is Georgia, about 650km away, at the border between Florida and Georgia just north of Macclenny.
Other promising candidates could have been Texas and Montana, but all locations in those two states are closer to a state border than 650km.

I guess that depends on how you define "contiguous". Key West is not connected to the US mainland by land, only by bridges...

@Doc As of 2024, "contiguous US" is usually understood to mean the entirety of the 48 US states excluding Alaska and Hawaii. This appears to be how Wikipedia defines it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_extreme_points_of_the_United_States#Southernmost_points
